Can I use route tables in Azure hub-and-spoke topology to route outbound HTTP requests to go through hub's NAT Gateway?
I have a hub and spoke topology in Azure so that spoke vnets are peered to hub. I have function apps running in spoke vnets and I'd like to route outbound connections from those through the hub's NAT Gateway so that all traffic would get one IP address for the HTTP requests.
Question: Is this possible with route table rules or do I need some network virtual appliance (NVA) to hub vnet to work as a "proxy"? ..or if NVA is mandatory for this to work, then what could be the cheapest option (small VM? load balancer?)
Microsoft does have this example for hub-and-spoke but it has simple VM as a NVA there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nat-gateway/tutorial-hub-spoke-route-nat
I'd like to keep cost as small as possible so looking for ways to avoid setting up a VM for that purpose.

I have tried various azurerm_route rules but feels that it would need to be VirtualAppliance next_hop_type but then I'd need (private?) IP address of NAT gateway which doesn't have any.
resource "azurerm_route" "example" {
  name                   = "from_spoke_to_hub_nat_gw"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  route_table_name       = azurerm_route_table.example.name
  address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
  next_hop_in_ip_address = ?
}


Without NVA its not possible, you can follow the MS DOC for your requirement.

@VenkatV thanks for confirming this. I was reaching the same conclusion after sweating with route rules  Any tips for cheapest VNA option there? In MS DOC you linked mentions Firewall but that's a bit overkill for my case when even cheapest plan is ~250€/mnth. Does Standard Load Balancer also work for this NVA purpose (~$25/mnth)?

I am afraid I am not aware of 3rd party NVAs, you can check in Azure Marketplace. Alternatively, you can deploy a second NAT Gateway in the Spoke Subnet and use an IP from Public IP address prefix which gives you a range of Public IPs (which you can use to whitelist)

@VenkatV thanks. Using NAT Gateway per spoke would also become expensive quickly so I'll look into setting up Azure Load Balancer in the hub for this purpose. I'll leave the question open if someone comes up with some "cheapest+easiest" NVA setups for this purpose.

You can check the Azure Marketplace for the cheapest and easiest NVA.
Alternatively, you can use any method below for your requirement.
Method: 1
You can deploy a second NAT Gateway in the spoke subnet and use an IP from Public IP address prefix which gives you a contiguous range of Public IPs (which you can easily whitelist)
Method : 2
You can use Azure Firewall as a NVA in Hub , Follow the Integrate NAT gateway with Azure Firewall in a hub and spoke network for outbound connectivity for more details
